# XSD to validate XML with namespaced attribute

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I need to create an XSD to validate the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<thing:cardAuthRequestResponse 
    xmlns:thing="http://www.thing.com/thing" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <thing:request xsi:type="thing:GiftCardBalanceRequest" />
</thing:cardAuthRequestResponse>
```

I have tried various online XSD generators and validators (e.g. https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html & https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html) but none have produced an XSD that will validate the XML, with various errors.  The problem is around the namespaced type attribute: `xsi:type`

The following will validate (the `xsi` namespace is removed from the `type` attribute):

INPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<thing:cardAuthRequestResponse 
    xmlns:thing="http://www.thing.com/thing" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <thing:request type="thing:GiftCardBalanceRequest" />
</thing:cardAuthRequestResponse>
```

XSD

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.thing.com/thing" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="cardAuthRequestResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="request">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:QName" name="type"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Can I alter the XSD to validate the XML with the namespaced type attribute or is there something fundamentally invalid about the XML?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your xml is attempting to create a dynamic list of xsd types which then contain content and can be validated. This is not wrong to do with xml but I would be surprised if an auto generated schema could understand this goal.

I reworked some of your namespaces to get them to actually link up and work together to create a sample of how this might look.

**XSD** - Simply defines that you have a `cardAuthRequestResponse` with any number of `request` elements in it. These can be of `xs:anyType`.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.enactor.com/retail">
    <xs:element name="cardAuthRequestResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="request" type="xs:anyType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="GiftCardBalanceRequest">
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="AgeRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="age">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:nonNegativeInteger" />
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This would allow you to validate this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<retail:cardAuthRequestResponse
        xmlns:retail="http://www.enactor.com/retail"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <retail:request xsi:type="retail:GiftCardBalanceRequest" numRequests="2" />
    <retail:request xsi:type="retail:AgeRequest" numRequests="2">
        <retail:age>2</retail:age>
    </retail:request>
</retail:cardAuthRequestResponse>
```

Now here you can see the `AgeRequest` I made up now allows you to validate to those specific elements.

Now there is 1 down side to this method, the `request` extends an `xs:anyType`. This means you could put `<retail:request><foobar/>2</retail:request>` and it would also be valid. There is a fix however which you may want if you dummed down your sample to simplify it.

---

#### Method 2

This makes your xsd more strongly typed and restricts what types can be defined by your `request`. It would allow you to make base attribute and element requirements of all `request` elements. For example:

**XSD** - Simply defines that you have a `cardAuthRequestResponse` with any number of `request` elements in it. These can be of `retail:baseRetailRequest`.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:retail="http://www.enactor.com/retail"
           targetNamespace="http://www.enactor.com/retail">
    <xs:element name="cardAuthRequestResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="request" type="retail:baseRetailRequest" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="baseRetailRequest">
        <xs:attribute name="numRequests" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" use="required"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="GiftCardBalanceRequest">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="retail:baseRetailRequest">
                <xs:sequence></xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="AgeRequest">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="retail:baseRetailRequest">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="age">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:nonNegativeInteger" />
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Now as each `<request>` is required to have a `numRequests` attribute defined for them. This might be useful if you have a base request which they must all fill out. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<retail:cardAuthRequestResponse
        xmlns:retail="http://www.enactor.com/retail"
        xmlns:thing="http://www.thing.com/thing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <retail:request xsi:type="thing:GiftCardBalanceRequest" numRequests="2" />
    <retail:request xsi:type="thing:AgeRequest" numRequests="2">
        <thing:age>2</thing:age>
    </retail:request>
</retail:cardAuthRequestResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your XSD is not a valid schema, because the name attribute of xs:attribute must be an NCName (so `xsi:type` is invalid).

Normally, if you want to allow an attribute in a different namespace from the targetNamespace of the schema, you would declare it in a different schema document with its own targetNamespace, import that schema document, and refer to the attribute using "ref" rather than "name".

But `xsi:type` is special: it's implicitly declared and implicitly allowed on any element. So you can simply remove the reference to `xsi:type` from your schema.

The next problem is that your instance document is in namespace `http://www.thing.com/thing`, while your schema defines namespace `http://www.enactor.com/retail`. I'm not sure whether this is a simple copy/paste error made when posting your question, or if you have fundamentally failed to understand the significance of namespaces in ensuring schema validity.

If I fix that problem, I'm left with one error:

Validation error on line 6 column 62 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: Unknown type {thing:GiftCardBalanceRequest} specified in xsi:type attribute

That's because the semantics of `xsi:type` require its value to be the name of a type that is declared in the schema, and your schema contains no such type.

Oh, and there is no point trying to write a declaration for xsi:type into a schema for any document; it is used by a schema validator to select a type for an element (specifically, to override the default type assignment), but it is not validated against the declaration of the element.  It's not an error to write a schema document for the xsi namespace, but it won't be used by any conforming processor.

Answer (score 0):

> ... is there something fundamentally invalid about the XML?

There is no XML instance for which it is impossible to construct a schema against which it is valid. There are and can be no "fundamentally invalid" XML documents.

In the case at hand, you should probably invest an hour or two reading up on the use of the xsi:type attribute; it is used to specify the name of a type present in the schema used for validation, to override the default type assigned to the element.

The minimum required to make the instance valid is a schema with

1. a declaration of an element whose qualified name is `{http://www.thing.com/thing}cardAuthRequestResponse` which allows a valid element instance to contain a single element named `{http://www.thing.com/thing}request` as content;
2. a declaration for element `{http://www.thing.com/thing}request` which assigns it some named type for which derivations of derived types is not blocked; and
3. a top-level type definition for a type named `{http://www.thing.com/thing}GiftCardBalanceRequest`, which is derived from the type assigned in item 2 to the element `{http://www.thing.com/thing}request`.

For example:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.thing.com/thing"
            xmlns:thing="http://www.thing.com/thing"
            xmlns:xsd="..."
            ... >
  <xsd:element name="cardAuthRequestResponse"/>
  <xsd:element name="request"/>
  <xsd:type name="GiftCardBalanceRequest"/>
</
```

It is not surprising that a tool for generating schemas might not be prepared for an instance containing an xsi:type attribute:  xsi:type is used to point to a type in an existing schema, and if a schema already exists, the tool may well wonder why anyone is running it.

If you are creating the XML yourself, why are you using xsi:type?

If you are receiving the XML from someone else, have you asked where the schema documents are?